# Getting Browser Enablement test as Fail while testing for Chrome browser in RFT

Tags: google-chrome, automation, rft

As my application only support Chrome browser and try to test it using IBM RFT.

Issues:

1. Browser enablement test is fail while testing Chrome from Enable Environment in RFT
2. Due to that not able to capture any objects in Chrome using RFT

Tried the below steps as well but not able to resolve :
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=1e5ec381-03c3-4ab6-a9b8-4ce98f592b3b

If anyone face the same issue previously please do reply.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Chrome 45(Where NPAPI is disabled ) or above , you need to install RFT  8.6.0.5  on top of which a test fix is available that will allow you to execute/playback your existing scripts. To get the testfix you will need to contact the product technical support.

Comment: as i am starting with new scripting in chrome so might be playback patch will not be helpful for us

Comment: I think you should try the patch .. there are some issues  with recording in terms of frames  etc but otherwise it is  fine ..  Also you would be able to use the find api

Answer (score 0):

Rational Functional Tester old versions doesn't work with Chrome anymore. In their last [release notes (fix pack 4)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/SSBLQQ_8.7.0/com.ibm.rational.test.ft.readme.doc/topics/readme.html) the greatest "feature" is to make it work with newer versions of Chrome. I have the version just before this one and I guarantee that it doesn't work with Chrome. The update process is really error prone. Reserve at least day to do it.